# Updating raphael path, that is connected to two elements, on those elements' drag

Tags: jquery, raphael, element, gsap

I have a number of divs, animated with gsap. Any two divs can be connected with raphael path, as they are in attached codepen. Currently, the connection is maintained by re-drawing the paths every 10ms, but that can drop rendering performance by over a half on slower machines. Is there a better way to maintain such connection?

Ideally i would have an update function attached to every path, that I could call everytime the div is dragged, but I can't get my head around it. 
I would appreciate any answer that would provide a solution or lead me in the right direction.

With Best Regards,
Patrick.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/mussler/pen/hfIlp

Code:

```
    RaphaelCont = Raphael("menu", "100%", "100%");

var getXY = function(obj, center) {
    center = center || false;
    var obx;
    var oby;
    obx = $(obj).offset().left - $(obj).parent().offset().left;
    oby = $(obj).offset().top - $(obj).parent().offset().top;
    if (center) {
        obx = obx + $(obj).outerWidth() / 2;
        oby = oby + $(obj).outerHeight() / 2;
    }
    return [obx, oby];
};
// Return Control Point coordinates for Bezier curve between two objects. Takes in array of xy coordinates
var getQP = function(xy, xye) {
    var xq = (xy[0] + xye[0]) / 2;
    var yq = (xy[1] + xye[1]) / 2;
    yq = yq * 1.3; // Create arch
    return [xq, yq];
}
var constructCurve = function(R, obj1, obj2, c) { //Creates a quadratic bezier curve between obj1 and obj2, using CSS ID, in a given Raphael object (R), in c color
    this.obj1 = obj1;
    this.obj2 = obj2;
    var xy = getXY(obj1, true);
    var xye = getXY(obj2, true)
    var xyq = getQP(xy, xye);
    var xq = xyq[0];
    var yq = xyq[1];
    //Create Curve
    var path = [
            ["M", xy[0], xy[1]],
            ["Q", xq, yq, xye[0], xye[1]]
        ],
        curve = R.path(path).attr({
            stroke: c,
            "stroke-width": 12,
            "stroke-linecap": "round"
        });
    setInterval(function() { // Update the curve every 10ms
        var xy = getXY(obj1, true);
        var xye = getXY(obj2, true);
        var xyq = getQP(xy, xye);
        path[0][1] = xy[0];
        path[0][2] = xy[1];
        path[1][1] = xyq[0];
        path[1][2] = xyq[1];
        path[1][3] = xye[0];
        path[1][4] = xye[1];
        curve.attr({
            path: path
        });
    }, 10);
}

// HOME - BEZIER TWEENS
var initMenuTweens = function() {
TweenMax.to($("#menu-home"), 8, {bezier: {type: "cubic",values: [{x: "+=0",y: "+=0"}, {x: "+=20",y: "+=20"}, {x: "+=-20" ,y: "+=0"}, {x: "+=0",y: "+=0"}]}, repeat: -1, ease: SlowMo.ease.config(0.5, 0.1)});
    TweenMax.to($("#menu-projects"), 6, {bezier: {type: "cubic",values: [{x: "+=0",y: "+=0"}, {x: "+=-5",y: "+=5"}, {x: "+=15",y: "+=-5"}, {x: "+=0",y: "+=0"}]},repeat: -1,ease: SlowMo.ease.config(0.5, 0.1)});
    TweenMax.to($("#menu-about"), 4, {bezier: {type: "cubic",values: [{x: "+=0",y: "+=0"}, {x: "+=0",y: "+=-15"}, {x: "+=-15",y: "+=-15"}, {x: "+=0",y: "+=0"}]},repeat: -1,ease: SlowMo.ease.config(0.5, 0.1)});

};


    Draggable.create("#menu-home , #menu-projects, #menu-about", {
        type: "x, y",
        bounds: window,

         onDragEnd:function()
 {
 TweenLite.getTweensOf(this.target)[0].invalidate().play();
 }
    });
 initMenuTweens();
constructCurve(RaphaelCont, "#menu-home", "#menu-projects", "#fff");
constructCurve(RaphaelCont, "#menu-home", "#menu-about", "#fff");
```

Comment: cool pen, one simple thing to do would be to cut the interval down to 30ms, it will probably still look fine that way.

Comment: It does slightly increase the performance, tough on my target crappy device, where i test live performance (6 years old win7 laptop, nothing fancy then and now), rendering rate is at about 20-25 fps, which creates 'laggy' feeling.

Comment: thats also because IE is using VML instead of SVG and VML is quite slow to animate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out a way to avoid setInterval.

Firstly, I pushed the update function as Raphael custom Attribute:

```
    RaphaelCont = Raphael("menu", "100%", "100%");
    RaphaelCont.customAttributes.update = function(){
            var xy = getXY(this.data('startObj'), true);
            var xye = getXY(this.data('endObj'), true);
            var xyq = getQP(xy, xye);
            var path = [["M", xy[0], xy[1]],["Q", xyq[0], xyq[1], xye[0], xye[1]]];
            this.attr({path: path});};
```

Function getXY and getQP remain unchanged.

Then, I modify the custructCurve function like this:

```
    var constructCurve = function(R, obj1, obj2, c) { //Creates a quadratic bezier curve between obj1 and obj2, using CSS ID, in a given Raphael object (R), in c color
    var xy = getXY(obj1, true);
    var xye = getXY(obj2, true)
    var xyq = getQP(xy, xye);
    //Create Curve
    var path = [
            ["M", xy[0], xy[1]],
            ["Q", xyq[0], xyq[1], xye[0], xye[1]]
        ];
    var curve = R.path(path).attr({
            stroke: c,
            "stroke-width": 8,
            "stroke-linecap": "round"
        });
        curve.data('startObj', obj1);
        curve.data('endObj', obj2);
    return curve;
}
```

I add startObj and endObj data to the curve.

Lastly, when creating a curve, I assign them to variables and push them in an array"

```
var RaphaelCurves = [];
RaphaelCurves.push(constructCurve(RaphaelCont, menu_home, menu_projects, "#fff"));
    RaphaelCurves.push(constructCurve(RaphaelCont, menu_home, menu_skills, "#fff"));
    RaphaelCurves.push(constructCurve(RaphaelCont, menu_home, menu_contact, "#fff"));
    RaphaelCurves.push(constructCurve(RaphaelCont, menu_home, menu_about, "#fff"));
```

Now, I can call RaphaelCurves[index].attr({update: "foo"}) at any point (foo is just a filler to match Raphael, throws error if nothing is present after update: ).

In my case, i link it to TweenMax.tick event:

```
    TweenMax.ticker.addEventListener("tick", myFunction);
        function myFunction(event) {
         for(var i=0; i<RaphaelCurves.length; i++) {
             RaphaelCurves[i].attr({update: "foo"});
            }
        }
```

Here's the updated codpen: http://codepen.io/mussler/pen/JgcEh